# Where can I find a lot of data to feed it an artificial intelligence?

Tags: email, chat, artificial-intelligence, datasource, communication

I want to code an artificial intelligence. To teach her the language I can use Wikipedia offline but for teaching her communication I need other sources. Do you know big data sources which fit to this task and are free available? For example chat protocolls, mails, content of forums or something similar?

Comment: The answer really is everywhere and anywhere, depending on the purpose of your AI machine.  A good idea is to link it to a search engine API, such as Bing (yes, I know), which is free to use given certain limitation, searches per day for example.  Pending that I don't think you're an AI referring to yourself in the third person?

Answer (score 0):

> for teaching her communication I need other sources.

Some ideas:

- Search video transcriptions on youtube (you may need to edit them for quality)
- Search in your country political debates transcriptions (they maybe available for free on internet)
- Search for theater plays dialogs in public domain